# ADF - How do I cancel an action from a commandbutton?

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I need to be able to cancel navigation from the action method on a commandbutton if some validation fails?  How do I cancel the action?

Currently, the app notifies the user of the failed validation, but the navigation still continues to the next page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use both actionListener and action, as described in this blog:
http://andrejusb.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/how-to-disable-action-conditionally.html